# How would you achieve this text layout in HTML/CSS without lists?

Tags: html, css, layout

[image: required layout with aligned hanging indents]

## Edit/Apology: forgot that it has to be done without lists.

Curious how you would achieve the layout in the included image in HTML/CSS *without using lists*. The reason is that it's a legal document and the list dotpoints have to be exactly the same as a paper document, i.e. they have to be **(a)**, they can't be **a)** or **a.** We can't 100% trust the browser to render `<ol type="a">` the way we expect.

Note that there is more than one space between the numbered/lettered dotpoints and the start of the paragraph text, and the later lines of the hanging indents should line up with the left-hand edge of the paragraph text.

I can get this type of layout using `&nbsp;` to force spacing, but I think of that as cheating. Also it would have to be manually adjusted as soon as we had two-digit numbers.

Anyone got any good ideas?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED: **Must accommodate lots of text (wrapping to margin)**. 
Use divs with custom CSS like counters and :before psuedo-element:

### HTML

```
<div class="outer-list">
  <div>thing 1
  </div>
  <div>thing 2
  </div>
  <div class="inner-list">
    <div>subthing 2.1
    </div>
    <div>subthing 2.2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl
      ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum
      zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui
      facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus
      parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
    </div>
    <div>subthing 2.3
    </div>
    <div>subthing 2.4
    </div>
    <div>subthing 2.5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>thing 3
  </div>
  <div>thing 4
  </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

UPDATED: use absolute positioning on the :before elements to place them outside the margin.

```
.outer-list {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  counter-reset: my-clever-counter;
}

.outer-list > div {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.outer-list > div:not(.inner-list):before {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  content: counter(my-clever-counter);
  counter-increment: my-clever-counter;
}

.inner-list {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.inner-list > div {
  margin-left: 0rem;
  padding-left: 3rem;
}
.inner-list > div:before {
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  left:1.4rem;
}
.inner-list > div:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "(a)";
}

.inner-list > div:nth-child(2):before {
  content: "(b)";
}

.inner-list > div:nth-child(3):before {
  content: "(c)";
}

.inner-list > div:nth-child(4):before {
  content: "(d)";
}

.inner-list > div:nth-child(5):before {
  content: "(e)";
}
```

See my updated [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/asonnenshine/pen/mEQLKP)

Comment: See apology: needs to be without using lists.

Comment: Hi thanks, however it fails the test on longer lines in the subthings wrapping correctly on the second or subsequent lines. If you extend `subthing 2.1` to be 200 words long for instance.

Comment: Updated example to accomodate 200+ words of text

Answer (score 1):

Just use nested listing and adjust the padding as you need

**HTML**

```
<ol>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
  <ol class="alpha">
    <li>asdasd</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
.alpha{
  list-style:lower-alpha;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/yJQKVZ)

**EDIT**

A way of doing it without lists

**HTML**

```
<div class="intro">
  <p><span class="num">1.</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  <div class="sub-intro">
    <p><span class="alpha">(a)</span>simply dummy text of the printing and typesetimply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industryimply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industryting industry</p>
    <p><span class="alpha">(b)</span>simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry imply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
    <p><span class="alpha">(c)</span>simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry imply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industryimply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
    <p><span class="alpha">(d)</span>simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry imply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.num{
  padding:0 10px;
}
.alpha{
  padding: 0 10px 0 33px;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/yJQKVZ)

Comment: See apology: needs to be without using lists.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel Updated

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```css
#number {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
}

#header {
  display: inline-block;
}

.line {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.spacer {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p id="number">1.</p>
<p id="header">This is a fancy header.</p>
<p class="line">(a)<span class="spacer"></span>This is my first line</p>
<p class="line">(a)<span class="spacer"></span>This is my second line</p>
<p class="line">(a)<span class="spacer"></span>This is my third line</p>
<p class="line">(a)<span class="spacer"></span>This is my fourth line</p>
<p class="line">(a)<span class="spacer"></span>This is my fifth line</p>
<p class="line">(a)<span class="spacer"></span>This is my sixth line</p>
```

Comment: See apology: needs to be without using lists.

Comment: No lists here! Take a look at the code before commenting ;)